# How to register vdhx file as WSL 2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two separate drivers (let's call them C and D). I had Windows installed on C and a vdhx file (containing a WSL installation) on driver D. I had to reinstall Windows (hence, WSL) on C, but the vdhx file still available on D.

Is there a way to register this existing vdhx file as a WSL 2 distro or would I need to recreate the distro from scratch?

I've tried using `wsl.exe --import` but it seems to work only for tar files. I also came across `wslconfig.exe` and saw a switch to unregister a distro, but not to register a new one.

Comment: Looks like [at minimum you will need to move the WSL distro to C:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#troubleshooting-installation)...

Comment: Hey @T2PS, thanks for the link. I was hoping to be able to install it on a different driver for two reasons.
1 - my C drive doesn't have much space
2 - if anything happens with Windows, I won't lose my data
I'm taking a look around, trying to find if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure worked for me:

1. Open regedit and navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`. Under this key there is a subkey that looks like a GUID, for each installed distro. Find the one that you want to move to different disk, and export it.
2. run `wsl --unregister DistroName` so that you can move the files
3. move your distro to another location
4. open the .reg file you exported in step 1, update `BasePath` value to point to the new location.
5. import the .reg file